# How to convert build.xml to maven pom file?

Tags: ant, maven

I have a portlet project which runs using build.xml. I want to shift to maven-based build management.

1. How can I map build.xml to pom.xml?
2. How can I write a goal for every target in build.xml?
3. Is it a good idea to use maven maven-antrun-plugin-1.6 for running ant tasks from pom.xml or not?
4. How can I put jars from the build path to repository?

Answer (score 4):

1. You simply can't because Maven has a [build life-cycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html)
2. You have to understand that Maven has a [build life-cycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) and that is your plan. You must forget the Ant Targets.

   The lifecycle has for example test-compile (compile the unit tests) and compile (compiling your production code. And further steps are running the unit tests and finally packaging your production code into a jar file.
3. It's not a good idea to use maven-antrun-plugin (only in very very very very rare cases).
4. Via mvn release:prepare release:perform or via mvn deploy (for SNAPSHOTs)

I recommend reading [Books about Maven](http://sonatype.com/Support/Books) in particular **Maven by Example** and **Maven: The Complete Reference**

If you are working for a company you should think hard about setting up a repository manager (for example Nexus or Archiva etc.).